# IE6 downloaded files cannot be opened unless saved to disk first

Tags: php, internet-explorer-6

I've read lots of information on the web regarding this and and plenty on stack overflow. Sadly, nothing worked.

Symptoms:

- IE6 only, on a Citrix Metaframe system...
- Download prompt appears, open the file, file not found, wathever the application
- Download prompt appears, save the file, file can be opened

Hints/information i know of:

- I roll back to a previous version of my code, and ie6 can download
- Tried to find the differences in code, none that output anything different per se
- Two headers changed:

  - Cache-Control: from "proxy-revalidate" to "no-cache, must-revalidate"
  - Set-Cookie: large value, session started now on each page

What i tried:

- Tried forcing the cache-control header to proxy-revalidate
- Removed the login script from the workflow of file downloads, this way the set-cookies don't happen again

I'm really stuck at all this, i have no way of finding out why IE6 only cannot download files in this new version, i've done all i could and worked on this issue for hours without having more clues.

If you have any information or more hints i could look at, could be really helpful, thanks!

**Edit #1**

File types are any types possible, but my tests are around: text/plain, application/pdf, Outlook message files

Comment: Have you tried force-download

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have done an edit for the file types

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Can you tell me what you mean by that, i searched for force-download and i get something about content-type specified as "application/force-download"

Comment: Finaly got it, a combination of force-download and cache-control: proxy-revalidate made it pass through

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Please get the answer out, i'll approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `header('Content-Type: application/force-download');`. This may help you.